# Jquery match text string but exclude some if part of a phrase

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a project where I need to identify gender specific terminology but ignore the match if it's included in a list of phrases. I can get the following to work, I'll assume it's very inefficient, but if I try to add any more terms to the list I think I'm exceeding character length for the line.  How could I code this better, is it possible to have two separate arrays - one for the list of words to search (including word boundaries) and another for the list of excluded phrases?  When the match is identified it's highlighted by a red box. Thanks.

```
$( '#body' ).filter(function(index,obj) {
            if(/\b(boy)\b|\b(girl)\b|\b(son)\b|\b(daughter)\b|\b(grandfather)\b|\b(grandmother)\b|\b(father)\b|\b(mother)\b|\b(de facto)\b|\b(de-facto)\b|\b(husband)\b|\b(wife)\b|\b(lady)\b|\b(female)\b|\b(woman)\b|\b(gentleman)\b|\b(male)\b|\b(man)\b|\b(uncle)\b/.test($(obj).clone().removeInnerElements().html().toLowerCase())){

                if(/(Wife Pension|Dad and Partner pay|Isle of Man|What a Man project)/.test($(obj).elements[0].innerHTML)) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
        $(obj).css("border","solid 3px red");
```

Comment: You can just put the individual terms into a JS array, then join it with the correct glue (e.g. `\b|\b` or `|`, depending on which filtering you are referring to) into a variable that you pass to the `.test()` method. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280920/convert-array-of-words-strings-to-regex-and-use-it-to-get-matches-on-a-string

Comment: Thanks for the reply Terry.  I looked at the link you provided don't have the confidence to work back from it.

Comment: If anyone could help me write it please I'd really appreciate it, then I can work backwards and understand how it all fits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone is interested here's the working solution.  Thank you Terry for responding:

```
$( '#body' ).filter(function(index,obj){

            var html = $(obj).clone().removeInnerElements().html().toLowerCase();

            var blackList = [
              "boy",  
              "girl",  
              "son",  
              "daughter",  
              "grand\\s?father",  
              "grand\\s?mother",  
              "father",  
              "mother",  
              "de\\s?facto",  
              "husband",  
              "wife",  
              "lady",  
              "female",  
              "woman",  
              "gentleman",  
              "male",  
              "man"  
            ];

            var allowedTerms = [
                "wife\\spension",
                "dad\\sand\\spartner\\spay",
                "isle\\sof\\sman",
                "what\\sa\\sman\\sproject"
            ];

            for (i in allowedTerms) {
                var re = new RegExp("\\b"+allowedTerms[i]+"\\b", "g");
                if (re.test(html)) {
                    html = html.replace(re, "");
                }
            }

            for (i in blackList) {
                var re = new RegExp("\\b"+blackList[i]+"\\b");
                if (re.test(html)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        },
    $(obj).css("border","solid 3px red");
```